# PostgreSQL - Pull earliest timestamp per user

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which records each time the user performs a certain behavior, with timestamps for each iteration. I need to pull one row from each user with the earliest timestamp as part of a nested query.

As an example, the table looks like this:

```
+ row | user_id | timestamp | description
+ 1   | 100     | 02-02-2010| android
+ 2   | 100     | 02-03-2010| ios
+ 3   | 100     | 02-05-2010| windows
+ 4   | 111     | 02-01-2010| ios
+ 5   | 112     | 02-03-2010| android
+ 6   | 112     | 02-04-2010| android
```

And my query should pull just rows 1, 4 and 5.

Thanks!

Comment: What does your query look like so far? The purpose of this site is not to do other people's work, but to help solve problems.

Comment: This is quite a basic query,look into aggregate functions and GROUP BY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be help. Don't understand your nested query part.

```
SELECT user_id, MIN(timestamp) AS min_timestamp
   FROM table1
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id;
```